# Raising arrays to a fractional index produces NaN?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have an array, *k* as demonstrated in my MWE. I want to raise this array to the power of 3/2 but when I do the quoted error arises.

```
import numpy as np
N = 2**15
dx = 0.1
k = (2 * np.pi / (N * dx)) * np.r_[0:N / 2, 0, -N / 2 + 1:0][None, :]
kpower = k**(3/2)
print(kpower)
```

> array([[0.        , 0.0018999 , 0.00537372, ...,        nan,        nan,
> nan]])

Why does this happen? I tried using np.power as well as

> scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power

What is the deal here since the array is real and features only integers.

Comment: Can you give us a fully working example? What are `N` and `dx`?

Comment: Sorry, edited! long day

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the entries of your array to complex numbers, so that numpy can perform your exponentiation:

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
dx = 2
k = (2 * np.pi / (N * dx)) * np.r_[0: N / 2, 0, -N / 2 + 1:0][None, :]

# convert array to complex datatype
k = k.astype(np.cdouble)

kpower = k**(3/2)
print(kpower)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00+0.j          4.98046397e-01+0.j
   1.40868794e+00+0.j          0.00000000e+00+0.j
  -1.68077199e-16-0.91496966j -3.23464720e-17-0.17608599j]]
```

Comment: ohhh, I see how that's done now. How do I take abs values of this?

Comment: np.absolute(kpower) gives you the elementwise absolute values